# How to pass const void *bytes to an Objective-C block from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdata

I'm writing some Swift (1.2) code that calls an Objective-C library (transcribing some earlier Objective-C code). It's not clear how it's supposed to work. I've tried a bunch of variations, and nothing satisfies the compiler. Here's the Objective-C code I started with:

```
// Objective-C

NSData *fileData = //

const void *bytes = fileData.bytes;
unsigned int bufferSize = 1024; //Arbitrary

[object writeDataWithBlock:
 ^BOOL(BOOL(^writeData)(const void *bytes, unsigned int length), NSError**(actionError)) {
     for (NSUInteger offset = 0; offset <= fileData.length; offset += bufferSize) {
         unsigned int size = (unsigned int)MIN(fileData.length - i, bufferSize);
         writeData(&bytes[i], size);
     }

     return YES;
 }];
```

So far, I've gotten as far as this Swift code:

```
// Swift

let fileData = //

let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(fileData.bytes)
let bufferSize = 1024 // Arbitrary

object.writeDataWithBlock() { (writeData, actionError) -> Bool in
    for var offset = 0; offset <= fileData.length; offset += bufferSize {
        let size = CUnsignedInt(min(fileData.length - offset, bufferSize))
        writeData(UnsafePointer<Void>(ptr[offset]), size)
    }

    return true
}
```

That's giving me this error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'UnsafePointer' that accepts an arguments list of type '(UInt8)'

When I remove the `UnsafePointer<Void>` conversion to do a more direct translation, yielding this line:

```
writeData(&ptr[offset], size)
```

I get this error, pointing at the `&` character:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Without the `&`, it yields a `UInt8`, giving me this error:

> Cannot invoke 'writeData' with an argument list of type '(Uint8, UInt32)'

What do I need to do to read the bytes out of the `NSData` sequentially and pass them onto another method?

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around `fileData.bytes`? And have you tried removing them?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel When I change it to `let ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = fileData.bytes`, the compiler errors out: `'Void' is not identical to 'UInt8'`

Comment: Maybe try changing that line to: `let ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = (Uint8*)fileData.bytes`

Comment: @MikeAtNobel That's not valid Swift code. When I try `let ptr = fileData.bytes as! UnsafePointer<UInt8>`, I get a warning complaining that they're unrelated types

Comment: So it's an UnsafePointer<Void> and that's what you're using inside your `writeData` method. Why not just save ptr as: `let ptr = fileData.bytes`?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel I had tried that, but when it was giving me compiler errors, I started searching, and arrived at casting it to a `UInt8`, because otherwise it would return no data. With an `&`, I get the `ambiguous without more context` message recorded in the question, and without it, it complains I can't pass `Void` into `writeData`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84617/discussion-between-dov-and-mikeatnobel).

Comment: @MikeAtNobel The pointer arithmetic you suggested in chat worked! Write it up in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic should (and does) get you the results you're looking for.

```
let fileData = //
let bufferSize = 1024 // Arbitrary

object.writeDataWithBlock() { (writeData, actionError) -> Bool in
    for var offset = 0; offset <= fileData.length; offset += bufferSize {
        let size = CUnsignedInt(min(fileData.length - offset, bufferSize))
        writeData(fileData.bytes + offset, size)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It never occurred to me to do the pointer arithmetic directly inline, in Swift

Comment: Yeah, it took me a bit to think of it too. Glad it worked out though.